# updatedb is generating an incomplete list of files

Tags: linux, locate

I'm running the following command:

```
updatedb -l 0 -o mydatabase.db -U /usr/myfiles1/
```

Then,

```
locate -d mydatabase.db ""
```

The "" are to show all the contents of mydatabase.db. However, I'm missing files that I'd expect to see in /myfiles1/. 'locate' doesn't seem to be recursing down through the directories. I've checked permissions, but it seems random as to what directories 'locate' chooses to recurse down into.

If I 'cd' to 'myfiles1' and then run 'updatedb', it recurses down into this directory and its subdirectories and generates all the files contained in /myfiles1/.

Comment: If you run `updatedb` with `-v` it should list the files it is finding, and this might provide a clue.

Comment: I tried this. It is skipping over a bunch of directories without recursing down into them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I wasn't able to recurse down into the subdirectories when updating the locate database, was because I didn't have the proper permissions for the top-level directories. Running updatedb as root was able to crunch through the whole file tree without skipping directories regardless of where I kicked of the updatedb command.